# How to rotate an arbitrary number of in-out parameters to a function (elegantly)?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, rotation, variadic-templates

`Input:  1, 2, 3, 4`

`Output: 2, 3, 4, 1`

**My solution:** [play with my code](https://godbolt.org/z/6rYq9K)

```
template <typename T, typename ... Param>
void rotate(T* first, Param* ... params) {
    std::vector<T*> tmp = {first, params...};
    if (tmp.size() <= 1) {return;}
    T f = *first;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < tmp.size(); ++i) {
        *tmp.at(i - 1) = *tmp.at(i);
    }
    *tmp.at(tmp.size() - 1) = f;
}
```

I would like to rotate any number of elements as described above. My solution seems to work, but in my eyes, it's not very "elegant". I do not like that I have to initialize a vector here. Is there a way to accomplish the same thing without the vector? Maybe with recursion?

Ideally, I would also like to pass references instead of pointers.

Comment: Reasonable question, but your `vector` solution could be made trivial by using `std::rotate`.

Comment: Nice. I did not know about `std::rotate`. Thank you very much for pointing that out! Still, Ideally I would use references and no vector. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an INCORRECT solution without using `std::vector`, where all arguments are passed by reference, and only a single element needs to be copied:

```
// THIS IS WRONG, SEE EDIT BELOW

template<typename T, typename ...Ts>
void rotate(T& first, Ts& ...rest) 
{
   auto first_copy = first; 
   std::tie(first, rest...) = {rest..., first_copy};
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sWbsqh).

---

Edit: The above solution is elegant, but is incorrect, since it appears that the order of assignments to `std::tuple` members is unspecified. The code above relies on the assignments to the arguments to `std::tie` to be done from left to right, so the solution doesn't work.

Here's a more verbose solution using `std::apply`, which is guaranteed to invoke the arguments of the passed in tuple in order:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Ts>
void rotate(T& first, Ts& ...rest) 
{
    auto first_copy = first;

    std::apply([&](auto&... lhs) {
        std::apply([&](auto&... rhs) {
            ((lhs = std::move(rhs)), ...); 
        }, std::tuple<T&, Ts&...>{rest..., first_copy});
    }, std::tuple<T&, Ts&...>{first, rest...});
}
```

While this is more verbose, unlike the first solution which does 1 copy-construction and N copy-assignments, this solution has the advantage that it only does 1 copy-construction and N move-assignments. This is not possible with the first solution, as far as I can tell. And obviously, it's correct, which is a big advantage too :)

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rxMjEj) that also shows the copies/moves made.

---

Here's an even simpler solution given by @max66, which is also as efficient as the solution with `std::apply`:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Ts>
void rotate(T& first, Ts& ...rest) 
{
  T first_copy{first}; 

  [&](auto& first_ref, auto & ... rest_ref) { 
      first = std::move(first_ref);
      (..., (rest = std::move(rest_ref))); 
  } (rest..., first_copy);
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EWbqq4).

Comment: Great! I've obtained almost the same with a reference wrapper and template folding. But this is more elegant and should works also with C++11.

Comment: Love it. Could you say a few words about `std::tie`, pls?

Comment: It's just a convenience when you have several variables, and want to assign values to those variables from a structure with multiple fields. It's closely related to structured bindings if you're aware of that.

Comment: @max66 Yeah, that's true, though `print` won't work since I'm using a fold expression. But `rotate` will :)

Comment: *only a single element needs to be copied*: No, actually you are [copy assigning entire elements](https://godbolt.org/z/Tx3ToG) for the shift/to rotate. Fo the integers won't be a problem though. BTW, nice approach ...+1!

Comment: @JeJo: 1 copy, n assignments.

Comment: @cigien: Are you sure that `tuple::operator=` should assign from left to right, I don't see any such constraints from [c++draft/tuple#assign](http://eel.is/c++draft/tuple#assign)...

Comment: @Jarod42 True, but does it matter in this case if the order is unspecified? Seems ok, since every variable is assigned to a unique different variable, and there are no circular assignments.

Comment: It matters, that's partially  why you introduce `first_copy` and not directly `std::tie(first, rest...) = {rest..., first};`. You assign tuple of reference to tuple of reference and `a=b; b=c; c=a_copy` give different results than `c=a_copy; b=c /*so a_copy*/; a=b /*so c so a_copy*/;`. (and it might be even less predictable as order might even differ than left-to-right or right-to-left).

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, you're absolutely right, the order matters. It's interesting, because the wording for assignment from `pair` explicitly says `first` and `second` are assigned in exactly that order. It's unclear for the others.

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh no, it seems the order *is* unspecified. So the solution is not actually correct. I wonder if there's a workaround ...

Comment: @cigien - what about creating before a tuple of values and after assigning it to the `std::tie()` tuple? I mean `std::tuple<Ts..., T>  t {rest..., first}; std::tie(first, rest...) = t;`

Comment: @max66 Sure, making copies of everything would certainly work, but it defeats the purpose of not using a `vector`.

Comment: @cigien - Yes... I suppose that the no-vector requirement is intended as no-container. It's a pity because the `std::tie()` way is really elegant.

Comment: @max66 Found a working solution :) Not as pretty, but at least it's correct, and more efficient than the old one too.

Comment: @cigien - not sure to completely understand your last version but... seems to me that can be simplified as follows:  `T first_copy{first}; [&](auto & f0, auto & ... rs) { ((first = std::move(f0)), ..., (rest = std::move(rs))); } (rest..., first_copy);`

Comment: @max66 Yes, that's a much nicer solution :) Do you want to add that to your answer, or should I just add it to mine?

Comment: @cigien - if you think it's a good improvement, add it to your answer.

Comment: @max66 Yes, it's definitely a good improvement. Added it to my answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Another use of template folding (so C++17 or newer is needed) without `std::vector` but using `std::reference_wrapper`

```
template <typename H, typename ... Ts>
void rotate (H & head, Ts & ... tail) {
    H h0 { head };
    std::reference_wrapper<H>  rw { head };

    ( (rw.get() = tail, rw = tail), ..., (rw.get() = h0) );
}
```

In C++11/C++14 you can simulate template folding initializing a C-style array

```
template <typename H, typename ... Ts>
void rotate (H & head, Ts & ... tail) {
    using unused = int[];
    H h0 { head };
    std::reference_wrapper<H>  rw { head };
    
    (void)unused { 0, (rw.get() = tail, rw = tail, 0)... };

    rw.get() = h0;
}
```

Comment: Just saw this, very clever use of `reference_wrapper` and fold expressions :)

Answer (score 2):

If you can use C++17... what about using template folding as follows ?

```
template <typename T, typename ... Param>
void rotate(T* first, Param* ... params) {
    std::array<T, 1u+sizeof...(params)> tmp = {*params..., *first};

    std::size_t  index {};

    ( (*first = tmp[index++]), ..., (*params = tmp[index++]) );
}
```

Works also with references

```
template <typename T, typename ... Param>
void rotate(T & first, Param & ... params) {
    std::array<T, 1u+sizeof...(params)> tmp = {params..., first};

    std::size_t  index {};

    ( (first = tmp[index++]), ..., (params = tmp[index++]) );
}
```

but you have to call it differently (obviously)

```
rotate(i, j, k, l, m, n);
```

Comment: OP's specifically asking for a solution without `vector`.

Comment: True @cigien. I still like this solution, because swapping `first` to the end of `tmp` will make things easier. Thanks

Comment: Though @cigien is right. I will not mark this as an answer

Comment: @cigien - Ops... you're right... and now? The OP seems appreciate it; what's the right things to do: delete or maintain it?

Comment: No, definitely don't delete it. It's a reasonable improvement to OP's solution, and it's useful to them.

Comment: @max66: Replace `std::vector` by `std::array` ;)

Comment: @Jarod42 - Yes :). And, maybe, is preferable (no dynamic allocation, size of the array known compile-time and, I suppose, better optimization). But I suppose that the OP "without the vector" requirement means "no container".